# React app testing with jest and enzyme error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am importing SVG's into my component and importing them as components using ReactComponent i.e.

import { ReactComponent as D1 } from '../../../assets/images/characteristics/D1.svg';
When I run jest/enzyme to test I get an error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

It appears I need to perhaps mock this? How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried with jest-svg-transformer and jest-transform-stub package but still not working

Comment: `import * as React from "react"; export default "SvgrURL"; const SvgrMock = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => ( <span ref={ref} {...props} /> )); export const ReactComponent = SvgrMock;`
Solve problem by adding above code to file svgrMock.js   and add these below lines to jest.config.js in moduleNameMapper 
`moduleNameMapper: { "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js", "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy", "\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/svgrMock.js", }`